React directives are not working after React 19 (canary) installation
I've installed React canary using

npm i react@canary
npm i react@next
npm i react@19.0.0-canary-4c12339ce-20240408

. I am trying to make some example with client or server component. Server component is not working as documentation says. For example useState() should not be available in a server component but this works:
"use server";

import { useState } from "react";

function ComponenteServer() {
  const now = new Date();
  const data = `${now.getHours()}:${now.getMinutes()}:${now.getSeconds()}`;

  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="orario-client">orario client: {data}</div>;
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>click</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default ComponenteServer;

I expected that an error occurs. For example, like when I use NextJs, an alert should advice me that useState() is not available.
